# Getting Image dimensions in symfony file upload

Tags: php, symfony, image-uploading

I was wondering if someone could tell me how to get the image dimensions of i file uploaded in symfony 2.8 with formbulder

The image entity had a property $file

```
/*
 * @Assert\Image(
 *     minWidth = 400,
 *     maxWidth = 1200,
 *     minHeight = 400,
 *     maxHeight = 1200
 * )
 */
public $file;
```

In the controller i build the form like this

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($image)
        ->add('file', FileType::class)
        ->add('title', TextType::class)
```

And then process the request

```
$form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted()) {

        $file = $image->getFile();
        if (!in_array($file->getClientMimeType(), self::$allowedMimeTypes)) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException(sprintf('Files of type %s are not allowed.', $file->getClientMimeType()));
        }

  [...]
```

I have two setter mehods

```
$image->setSizeX($x);
$image->setSizeY($y);
```

But cannot for the love of god figure out how to get $x and $y from the file object.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
 $info = getimagesize($file);
 list($x, $y) = $info;
```

Comment: thank you. there I was thinking symfony would have some hidden property on the file object, or have a special FileType for images where it stores its dimensions, when the real solution was so simple ;)